# Firestore: Paging using cursors

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why is query pagination not supported in server libraries (java/nodejs etc). I'm looking for paging through a large dataset on the server-side. Similar to GAE/J, preferably using a websafe cursor, which could be sent to the client.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server SDKs do support something like pagination, with caveats.

The web, Android and iOS SDKs allow you to use a document snapshot as the cursor for a query (using `startAfter`), which works like you'd expect. The server SDKs require specifying a set of *values* instead. If your values are unique, this works fine; if not, it isn't safe because a value with a duplicate could be the last element in the current batch:

```
current: 998, 999, 1000 | next: 1000, 1001, 1002
```

and using `startAfter` would skip the first element (1000) of the next batch of results. You can work around this by using `startAt` and unioning the results, but if there are more of the duplicate values than the batch size you specify, you could get stuck:

```
current: 1000, 1000, 1000 | next: 1000, 1001, 1002
```

Here's more on [paginating data with query cursors](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors) in Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Thanks Will. I'm thinking of the following for paging. Sort the collection by timestamp and set limit to <page_size> say 100, and use the timestamp from the last element  as the startAt for the next query. Do you see any problems with this approach? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hey, happy to help. Two concerns:

1. I'm guessing this is unlikely, but you're not going to have 100 identical timestamps, right? Otherwise you'll run into the second problem I describe.

2. Be careful with timestamps: at high volume, you may run into the limit on writes with sequential values (500 per second, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

Comment: (And don't forget to mark this as an answer if you consider it one. :) )

Comment: >> Be careful with timestamps: at high volume, you may run into the limit on writes with sequential values (500 per second)

This is a great catch. I did not notice this before. Thanks

Comment: I am using Java server SDK and looks like cursor based pagination (with `startAfter(QueryDocumentSnapshot)` works. Is this something new? The Firestore docs still say it is not supported.